# Best approach to model contacts in the Django modelling language

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

I am designing a contact relationship application that needs to store contacts in groups. Basically I have 7 "group types" (simplified it to 3 for my image), each group type shares the same fields so I thought that it would make sense to use an abstract "group", and let all group types inherit the methods from this abstract group.

So this is basically the idea:

[image: Group type A]

However, this approach results in a couple of unexpected difficulties. For example:

I am not able to use a foreignkey of an abstract class, so if I would want to model a relationship between a group and a contact, I have to use the following approach:

```
limit = (models.Q(app_label='groups', model="Group type A") |
         models.Q(app_label='groups', model="Group type B") |
         models.Q(app_label='groups', model="Group type C")
         )
group_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, limit_choices_to=limit)
group_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
group = GenericForeignKey('group_type', 'group_id')
```

This seems quite hacky, and with this approach I am forced to do some hard coding as well. I am not able to call all groups with a simple query, maybe a new group will be added in the future.

Is there a better approach to model a relationship like this? Am I using the abstract class completely wrong?

**Edit:** some extra explanation in response to the questions.
A user is connected to a group with another object called "WorkRelation", because there is some extra data that is relevant when assigning a user to a group (for example his function).

I initially went for an abstract class because I thought that this would give me the flexibility to get all Group types be just calling Group.objects.all(). If I would use a base model, the groups aren't connected and I will also have to hard-code all group names.

Comment: Do the child groups have additional fields or is it only their logic that changes?

Comment: No, they don't have any additional fields

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your child models do not have additional fields, you can make them [proxy models](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/models/#proxy-models) of the base group model. Proxy models do not create new database tables, they just allow having different programmatic interfaces over the same table.

You could then define your `ForeignKey` to the base group model:

```
group = ForeignKey(BaseGroup)
```

Use [django-polymodels](https://github.com/charettes/django-polymodels/blob/master/polymodels/models.py) or a similar app to have the groups casted to the right type when queried.

More on model inheritance [in the doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/models/#model-inheritance).

Answer (score 0):

Why don't use solid base model instead of abstract model? Then you just put `contacts` as either `ForeignKey` or `ManyToMany` to the base model.